# Wordpress, mass post inserts

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Currently I am looping over 3 thousand times in order to insert posts using the `wp_insert_post()` etc.

All these queries are a lot of hopping forward and back to the MySQL database. Do you know if it is possible to bulk all these queries as one query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how big is your each post? is your PHP memory webserver enough to do this?

Comment: Each post is about 7 fields, yea i'll probably have to increase memory :s

Comment: @TheNickYo can you explain further?, i think this can be done using MySQL stored procedure query.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to format all the posts you would like to insert in [the WordPress eXtended RSS (WXR) file format](http://devtidbits.com/2011/03/16/the-wordpress-extended-rss-wxr-exportimport-xml-document-format-decoded-and-explained/).

If you manage, then you can load all the posts in one shot using the built-in WordPress import utility.